# Group ring generated by $\mathbb Z$ and the quaternion group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-rings

> I would like to calculate general $n$th power of $i+j$ in the group ring.

My idea was to find some patterns after calculating some powers of $i+j$, conjecture the general form of $n$th power of it and prove it by induction. But I cannot find any patterns... So any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: How many powers did you compute?

Comment: Quaternion group (not "quarternion group").

Comment: It would help a lot if you show already calculated powers.